# Copying from Excel cells to Word cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have the word 'Apple' in different cells in a excel page as shown below. As you can see, each alphabet is in a different cell. When I go ahead and copy the word and try to paste it in a Microsoft Word cell, it pastes the entire word in just one Microsoft Word cell.

How can I make it such that the alphabets get pasted in each individual cell in my Word document?

This is the word that is in Excel:

[image: This is the word that is in Excel]

This is how Word pastes the word:

[image: This is how Word pastes the word.]

This is how I want Word to paste my word ( I want the word in separate cells):

[image: This is how I want Word to paste my word ( I want the word in separate cells.)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all cells in Word you want to paste, and paste the values from Excel:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I get the same kind of results you do when I simply go to Word, select a cell, and use any paste option I can find a way to select.

Mind you, the end is a little varied for some of them, but all are objectionable in that they are not the clear and definite result that YOU desire.

However...

If I change what I'm doing from (see first line, above) `select a cell`, as in "cell", singular, to "cells", plural, all is good.

If you select the cells you want the result in (five contiguous cells in this case), THEN paste using `Overwrite Cells (O)` or `Keep Text Only (T)` choices, you will get your one letter per Word table cell.

(The first seems to bring Excel formatting along which can alter more than just font, say, including row height. The second uses Word's current formatting.

Non-contiguous pasting seems to start at the first letter in each block of cells, so using the last four cells of a row, and the first of the next is a non-starter. At least doing so in a single step... of course one has a hundred ways to do it using multiple steps.